# Are there any chassis that accept a NUC board but accommodate more than one drive?

Tags: nas, nuc

I am exploring options for a network attached storage system, but I want to have full control over the hardware, so a prepackaged system is not a viable solution.

Size is not a significant concern, but I have access to free Intel NUC units, so I'd like to make use of one (the specific model is something I can pick at the time I decide to get it). There are mini-PCIe RAID controllers like [this Syba unit](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124074) that I can use to connect a couple drives.

What I can't seem to find is a chassis that can accept a NUC board but has space for two (or even better, three, because the NUC has it's own SATA port) 2.5" or 3.5" drives. Every chassis I've seen only fits one 2.5" drive.

Comment: NUC is definitely out of the question, how small does the unit have to be? Do you have any cost constraints?

Comment: @PeterZhu I tweaked the question to address the size, which is to say it doesn't really matter. Cost isn't a super huge concern, but hey... if I can get a NUC for free, why not try to use it? This is for personal use, rather than anything that needs to be repeatable.

Comment: I can't find any NUC cases that allow multiple 2.5" drives. You could always do the ghetto duct tape method or custom design a case and have it 3D printed.

Comment: Probably not the best idea, but you could custom make a chassis, either out of metal or wood.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth it to look into 3.5" drive enclosures. I've got an aluminium one which is a little oversized for a 3.5" drive and which has just the right size for a NUC board and some 2.5" drives (30mm height in total).[image: Picture of mine.]
 It even has a status LED (that's the cable you see) and a kind of sled onto which I can mount stuff.

[This might be something you can actually order](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009CXPZVK) for $15, but really I meant to give general advice and not a specific product.

It should be

- aluminium so it transfers heat outside
- preferably have this kind of sled so you can screw the NUC board onto it and still get it out of the case

Comment: If you're going to recommend this component, you need to include its name and preferably a link to it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I was trying to recommend components like this in general - I don't think this is available anymore, is like 5 years old.

Comment: @Nobody Answers should generally recommend one specific piece of hardware, rather than a general class. General thoughts can go in comments.